# GitHub API: Enable Push Restrictions for branch

Tags: python, git, github, github-api

I am trying to disable and enable branch protections for a GitHub project in a Python script using the GitHub API (Version 2.11). More specifically I want to remove all push restrictions from a branch and later enable them with specific teams.

Replacing/adding existing team restrictions works via

```
PUT/POST /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection/restrictions/teams
```

And removing push restrictions also works like a charm using

```
DELETE /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection/restrictions
```

But, if I remove the push restrictions, I have found no way how to enable it back again to add specific teams. If I try to add or replace teams, the message says **'Push restrictions not enabled'**.

So how can I enable the checkbox *Restrict who can push to this branch* to add teams in a script? See screenshot for the desired outcome: [Push Restrictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9Sf9.png)

The API documentation just presents me the options *[Get restrictions of protected branch](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.11/v3/repos/branches/#get-restrictions-of-protected-branch)* and *[Remove restrictions of protected branch](https://developer.github.com/enterprise/2.11/v3/repos/branches/#remove-restrictions-of-protected-branch)*.

What I tried so far:

- Just removing all teams without removing the restrictions does not work, because then nobody is able to push.
- Sending PUT/POST to */repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection/restrictions* gives a 404.
- Right now I have no other way than clicking the checkbox manually, then adding and replacing works via API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [Update branch protection](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#update-branch-protection) section of Github API Rest :

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection
```

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) & [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) :

```bash
ownerWithRepo="MyOrg/my-repo"
branch="master"
curl -X PUT \
     -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github.luke-cage-preview+json' \
     -H 'Authorization: Token YourToken' \
     -d '{
        "restrictions": {
            "users": [
              "bertrandmartel"
            ],
            "teams": [
              "my-team"
            ]
        },
        "required_status_checks": null,
        "enforce_admins": null,
        "required_pull_request_reviews": null
    }' "https://api.github.com/repos/$ownerWithRepo/branches/$branch/protection"
```

Note that setting `null` to one of those fields will disable(uncheck) the feature

In [python](/questions/tagged/python) :

```python
import requests 

repo = 'MyOrg/my-repo'
branch = 'master'
access_token = 'YourToken'

r = requests.put(
    'https://api.github.com/repos/{0}/branches/{1}/protection'.format(repo, branch),
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.luke-cage-preview+json',
        'Authorization': 'Token {0}'.format(access_token)
    },
    json = {
        "restrictions": {
            "users": [
              "bertrandmartel"
            ],
            "teams": [
              "my-team"
            ]
        },
        "required_status_checks": None,
        "enforce_admins": None,
        "required_pull_request_reviews": None
    }
)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.json())
```

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. Initially I tried to avoid sending the whole bunch of data by just activating/deactivating the restrictions. But I guess this is the right way to do it. The only downside is, that I first need to GET the current config (because different branches in different projects may be configured differently) and then put this data into the PUT you mentioned.

Comment: The REST api documentation link for updating branch protections has recently been split into its own Branches topic - you can find it here now: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/branches#update-branch-protection