# Git branch restriction using git API & cURL

Tags: git, curl, github, gitlab

How can I use unix cURL and git API to restrict access to a team who can push to a branch.

Also, is there a way I can error handle this while using cURL?

Comment: check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51114758/2614364)

Comment: great! Thanks.. let me give it a try.